# How to resolve Mysql DB Error changing account admin access denied issue?

Tags: mysql, database, permissions, access-denied, dbaccess

We are rolling out a new DEV AWS Server. Here we are using mysql DB. I use Admin account to grant privileges to users, but it somehow is rejecting it. This was also the reason I wasn't able to export QA schema into Dev that I'm trying to do for my project. It could be something simple but because of this I'm not able to make progress. Can anybody throw some lights please?

Error Saving Account:

```
"Error changing account admin@%"; Access denied for user 'admin'@% (Using password: YES)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mysql root account lock issue. We updated using following command.

```
 SET PASSWORD FOR root@'localhost' = PASSWORD('password');
```

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: Followed following link to update root password. Updated commend. Here is the link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset